# Jest how to test a map contents i.e. key and value

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have an JSON object which has a map as follows:

```
{"name": "Bertha", [["id", "123"], ["status", "active"]]}
```

Please note that I am representing the map like it would be represented in typescript but I don't know how it would be represented in the underlying Jest framework. It is failing when I use the isEqual([["id", "123"....]) syntax. It is reporting that it received:

```
Map {"id" => "123", "status" => "active"} which I find quite confusing.
```

How do I test the key, value pairs using Jest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
[["id", "123"], ["status", "active"]]
```

is an array of arrays, not a Map.

This

```
Map {"id" => "123", "status" => "active"}
```

is the conventional syntax for a Map, which would be constructed by passing the array of arrays above into `new Map`.

Since it looks like what you actually have is a Map, not an array of arrays - to test that the map's key-values are as above, I'd take the Map's entries (to turn it from a Map back into an array of arrays). Then that structure can be deep checked with [`toEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#toequalvalue).

```
const entries = [...map.entries()];
expect(entries).toEqual([["id", "123"], ["status", "active"]]);
```

The other option (which wouldn't be very sustainable if you had many items in the Map) would be to check each one individually.

```
expect(map.get('id')).toBe(123);
expect(map.get('status')).toBe('active');
```

Comment: How do I get the map?

Comment: The value that was logged and produced the `Map {"id" => "123", "status" => "active"}` in your question is the Map - whatever you referenced there, you can reference again to call its `.entries()`.

Comment: It did not work unfortunately.   const entries = [ ...user.data.entries()]

Comment: What were you doing to produce the log `Map {"id" => "123", "status" => "active"}` you described in your question? All you should need to do is reference that again

Comment: expect(user.data).isEqual([["id", "123"], ["status", "active"]]).  Visual Studio code shows that user.data is a Map<string,string> when I hover over it.

Comment: If that's the Map, then to get its entries you can do `[...user.data.entries()]`

Comment: const entries = [...user.data!.entries()];
expect(entries).toEqual([["id", "123"], ["status", "active"]]);   This did not work

Comment: If `user.data` really is a Map containing the values said in the question, that looks reasonable. Can you be more specific on what doesn't work about it? What does Jest complain about?

Comment: Array [
    "id",
-     "123",
+     "active",
  ],
] is what is printed, makes no sense

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] in your question so that your problems can be reproduced and debugged